# 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' don't work with symfony 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twig, symfony

I'm a beginner in symfony3, I created a form and I would to design it by bootstrap so I tried to set :(in app/config/config.yml)

```
twig:
form_themes:
    - 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig'
```

and in my index.html.twig :

```
{% extends 'SosSecureBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig'  %}
{% block body %}
<h1>Hello Form</h1>
{{ form( form ) }}
{% endblock %}
```

[but dosn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAQm4.png)

Comment: Do you have bootstrap css and js included in your main layout (`SosSecureBundle::layout.html.twig`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all **this is redundant** if you already defined your theme in the config

```
{% form_theme form 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig'  %}
```

this can be used if your want to overwrite an already defined form element or want to extend the current themes if it's needed in the current context.

Second the configuration with yml-files can sometimes be kind of tricky, the line **indent** is very important take care that everything is in the **correct indent-level**

It should look like this:

```
twig:
    form_themes:
        - 'form/fields.html.twig'
```